# Filtering a string based on some group of characters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I would like to filter the string mentioned below in python.

`u'reviews': [{u'content':`

Can someone please let me know to how I should create a new string like this below.

`reviews: [{content:`

I am aware that python provides an excellent patter matching technique but don't know how it works. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
x="u'reviews': [{u'content':"
print re.sub(r"u'([^']*)'",r"\1",x)
```

You can use `re.sub` for this.

Comment: Hey @vks, I am trying to understand what this snippet of code does. Here, 

`r"u'([^']*'" means a pattern where any expression should fit between u' and ' except for ' 

r "\1" means it will repeat for once ?

Is that the correct understanding ?

Comment: @fritter_nation r"\1" means it will reaplce by content captrued inside `()`